# Interchange the order of summation

Tags: summation

if I have
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n} (\cos)^{n-p} (i\sin)^{p} x^n
$$
Now substituting $x^n= x^{n-p}x^{p}$ and using the transformation identity
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{j}f(i,j)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}f(i,j)$$
Here i = p; j = n-p
Then
$$=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n-p=0}^{\infty} (\cos)^{n-p} (i\sin)^{p}x^{n-p}x^{p} $$
Can I group it like
$$
=\sum_{n-p=0}^{\infty}(\cos)^{n-p}x^{n-p}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}(i\sin)^{p}x^{p}    
$$
Is my final equation correct?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product